# TikZ matrix positioning voodoo with column sep

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have tried many different things and I just can't wrap my head around how to work around the fact that the column sep option to TikZ's `\matrix` command changes the positioning of the matrix on the page. The code for my (rather large) picture is below with some added comments.

I would like to have a larger column sep than here (such as the 4em that's commented out below) while having the picture positioned such that the arrows down the middle are centered on the page. I can't see how this is possible without some *ugly* `\hspace` trial and error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,relsize,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{units}
\newcommand\onehalf{\nicefrac{1}{2}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}{\huge\textbf{Separation Properties}}\end{center}
%
\vspace{1ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\matrix (m) [nodes={draw,rectangle,thin,fill=blue!10},%
             row sep=1.7em,%column sep=4em,% Uncomment this to see m move around
             text depth=0.25ex,%
             draw=red] % Comment this out to not see the outline of the matrix
{%
\node (Met) {Metrizable};              & \node (T6) {P.\@ Normal Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{6}}$)}; & \node (PN) {P.\@ Normal}; \\
\node (Ord) {Total order};             & \node (T5) {C./H.\@ T$_4$ (T$_{\smash[b]{5}}$)};         & \node (HN) {C./H.\@ Normal}; \\
\node (CH) {Cpt.\@ Hausdorff};         & \node (T4) {Normal Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{4}}$)};      & \node (Norm) {Normal}; \\
\node (LCH) {Loc.\@ Cpt.\@ Hausdorff}; & \node (T3h) {Tychonoff (T$_{\smash[b]{3\onehalf}}$)};    & \node (CReg) {C.\@ Regular}; \\
\node (FH) {F./C.\@ Hausdorff};        & \node (T3) {Regular Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{3}}$)};     & \node (Reg) {Regular}; \\
                                       & \node (T2h) {Urysohn (T$_{\smash[b]{2\onehalf}}$)}; \\
                                       & \node (T2) {Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{2}}$)};             & \node (PReg) {Preregular (R$_1$)};\\
                                       & \node (T1) {T$_{\smash[b]{1}}$}; \\
                                       & \node (T0) {T$_{\smash[b]{0}}$}; \\
};
\path[->,thin]
(T3h)  edge [bend left=90]  node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.25]{$\scriptstyle\beta$} (T5)
(T0)   edge [bend right=60] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{\scriptsize+R$\scriptstyle_1$} (T2)
(PReg) edge [bend right=60] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{\scriptsize+Loc.~Cpt.} (CReg)
(Reg)  edge [bend right=80] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.70]{\scriptsize+Lindel\"{o}f} (Norm)
(Reg)  edge [bend right=80] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.75]{\scriptsize+2nd count.} (HN);
\path[->,thick] 
(T6)   edge node[]{} (T5)  (T6)  edge node[]{} (PN)
(T5)   edge node[]{} (T4)  (T5)  edge node[]{} (HN)
(T4)   edge node[auto]{\smaller UL} (T3h) 
    (T4)  edge node[]{} (Norm)
(T3h)  edge node[]{} (T3)  (T3h) edge node[]{} (FH)   (T3h) edge node[above,midway]{\smaller KEQ} (CReg)
(FH)   edge node[]{} (T2h)
(T3)   edge node[]{} (T2h) (T3)  edge node[above,midway]{\smaller KEQ} (Reg)
(T2h)  edge node[]{} (T2)
(T2)   edge node[]{} (T1)  (T2)  edge node[above,midway]{\smaller KEQ} (PReg)
(T1)   edge node[]{} (T0)
(PN)   edge node[]{} (HN)
(HN)   edge node[]{} (Norm)
(CReg) edge node[]{} (Reg)
(Reg)  edge node[]{} (PReg);
\path[->,thick]
(Met) edge node[]{} (T6)
(Ord) edge node[]{} (T5)
(CH)  edge [preaction={draw=white,-,line width=6pt}] node[]{} (T4)  (CH)  edge node[]{} (LCH)
(LCH) edge node[]{} (T3h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\"{o}` breaking the syntax highlighting was only in the _preview_. Yes, I know, it's really annoying that the preview is so different from the final result; it's already been a long time, but they haven't fixed it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit: I changed my original solution using \pgfresetboundingbox to this more elegant one**

You can position the matrix around a certain node using `matrix anchor=T6.north` in the matrix options, and make the `tikzpicture` crop the bounding box so it only contains the middle line of the matrix using `trim left=0pt,trim right=0pt` in the `tikzpicture` options. Then issuing `\centering` before the `tikzpicture` will center the image around the vertical middle arrows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,relsize,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,shapes}
\usepackage{units}
\newcommand\onehalf{\nicefrac{1}{2}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}{\huge\textbf{Separation Properties}}\end{center}
%
\vspace{1ex}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim left=0pt,trim right=0pt]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\small]
\matrix (m) [matrix anchor=T6.north,nodes={draw,rectangle,thin,fill=blue!10},%
             row sep=1.7em,column sep=4em,% Uncomment this to see m move around
             text depth=0.25ex,%
             ]
{%
\node (Met) {Metrizable};              & \node (T6) {P.\@ Normal Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{6}}$)}; & \node (PN) {P.\@ Normal}; \\
\node (Ord) {Total order};             & \node (T5) {C./H.\@ T$_4$ (T$_{\smash[b]{5}}$)};         & \node (HN) {C./H.\@ Normal}; \\
\node (CH) {Cpt.\@ Hausdorff};         & \node (T4) {Normal Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{4}}$)};      & \node (Norm) {Normal}; \\
\node (LCH) {Loc.\@ Cpt.\@ Hausdorff}; & \node (T3h) {Tychonoff (T$_{\smash[b]{3\onehalf}}$)};    & \node (CReg) {C.\@ Regular}; \\
\node (FH) {F./C.\@ Hausdorff};        & \node (T3) {Regular Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{3}}$)};     & \node (Reg) {Regular}; \\
                                       & \node (T2h) {Urysohn (T$_{\smash[b]{2\onehalf}}$)}; \\
                                       & \node (T2) {Hausdorff (T$_{\smash[b]{2}}$)};             & \node (PReg) {Preregular (R$_1$)};\\
                                       & \node (T1) {T$_{\smash[b]{1}}$}; \\
                                       & \node (T0) {T$_{\smash[b]{0}}$}; \\
};
\path[->,thin]
(T3h)  edge [bend left=90]  node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.25]{$\scriptstyle\beta$} (T5)
(T0)   edge [bend right=60] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{\scriptsize+R$\scriptstyle_1$} (T2)
(PReg) edge [bend right=60] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{\scriptsize+Loc.~Cpt.} (CReg)
(Reg)  edge [bend right=80] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.70]{\scriptsize+Lindel\"{o}f} (Norm)
(Reg)  edge [bend right=80] node[fill=white,inner sep=2pt,pos=0.75]{\scriptsize+2nd count.} (HN);
\path[->,thick] 
(T6)   edge node[]{} (T5)  (T6)  edge node[]{} (PN)
(T5)   edge node[]{} (T4)  (T5)  edge node[]{} (HN)
(T4)   edge node[auto]{\smaller UL} (T3h) 
    (T4)  edge node[]{} (Norm)
(T3h)  edge node[]{} (T3)  (T3h) edge node[]{} (FH)   (T3h) edge node[above,midway]{\smaller KEQ} (CReg)
(FH)   edge node[]{} (T2h)
(T3)   edge node[]{} (T2h) (T3)  edge node[above,midway]{\smaller KEQ} (Reg)
(T2h)  edge node[]{} (T2)
(T2)   edge node[]{} (T1)  (T2)  edge node[above,midway]{\smaller KEQ} (PReg)
(T1)   edge node[]{} (T0)
(PN)   edge node[]{} (HN)
(HN)   edge node[]{} (Norm)
(CReg) edge node[]{} (Reg)
(Reg)  edge node[]{} (PReg);
\path[->,thick]
(Met) edge node[]{} (T6)
(Ord) edge node[]{} (T5)
(CH)  edge [preaction={draw=white,-,line width=6pt}] node[]{} (T4)  (CH)  edge node[]{} (LCH)
(LCH) edge node[]{} (T3h);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: centered large tikzpicture]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wouldn't have found that out by reading the documentation. It didn't help that Ubuntu comes with an old version of TikZ, so I had to put the latest in ~/texmf to get this to work

Comment: This is the good answer. My first try was bad. Only fine if the matrix is alone on the page.